# React/NextJS using UseEffect Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in using ReactJS/NextJS. I am creating a carousel component to use an Image optimization feature in NextJS Framework. The carousel component works fine and I want to add carousel next slide automatically when a props for duration will be passed. I was trying to create a function inside `UseEffect` hook with `setTimeout` to perform my next slide.

I tried this code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from 'components/shared/carousel/carouselStyles.css';
import NavigateBeforeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/NavigateBefore';
import NavigateNextIcon from '@material-ui/icons/NavigateNext';
import Image from 'next/image';

const Carousel = (props) => {
  const { slides, slideshow } = props;

  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  const length = slides && slides.length;

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
  };

  if (!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0) {
    return null;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (slideshow > 0) {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        nextSlide();
      }, slideshow);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [current, slideshow]);

  return (
    <section className="slider">
      <NavigateBeforeIcon className="left-arrow" onClick={prevSlide} />
      <NavigateNextIcon className="right-arrow" onClick={nextSlide} />
      {slides.map((slide, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div
              className={index === current ? 'slide active' : 'slide'}
              key={index}
            >
              {index === current && (
                <Image
                  src={slide.feature_image}
                  alt="carousel_img"
                  className="image"
                  width={1600}
                  height={600}
                />
              )}
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
      <div className="dots-con">
        {slides.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
            <span
              className={index === current ? 'dot active' : 'dot'}
              key={index}
            ></span>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

but this gives me error of `Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render`

If I will comment the `useEffect`, then it works fine but doesn't came up with what I want which is to auto-play the carousel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move your condition after hook like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (slideshow > 0) {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        nextSlide();
      }, slideshow);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [current, slideshow]);


 if (!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0) {
        return null;
 }
```

read more here about react hook rules [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax issue in your useEffect Hook.

You should not wrap the written statement inside if condition.
It never executes the return of useEffect to clean up.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (slideshow > 0) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        nextSlide();
      }, slideshow);
    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [current, slideshow]);
```

Comment: share a code sandbox link for more detail